# How to filter this tree use Python?

Tags: python, tree

There is Python data structure like a tree.
I want to filter the `detect_obj == 1`'s node, the nested ID 8, the leaf detect_obj = 0, need to delete, and the ID 6 and 7 now is empty, also need to be deleted.
How to do it elegantly?

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "children": [],
        "detect_obj": 1,
        "isleaf": 1,
        "name": "1",
        "parent_id": None
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "children": [],
        "detect_obj": 1,
        "isleaf": 1,
        "name": "2",
        "parent_id": None
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "children": [],
        "detect_obj": 0,
        "isleaf": 1,
        "name": "3",
        "parent_id": None
    },
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "children": [],
        "detect_obj": 0,
        "isleaf": 1,
        "name": "4",
        "parent_id": None
    },
    {
        "ID": 5,
        "children": [],
        "detect_obj": 0,
        "isleaf": 1,
        "name": "5",
        "parent_id": None
    },
    {
        "ID": 6,
        "children": [
            {
                "ID": 7,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "ID": 8,
                        "children": [],
                        "detect_obj": 0,
                        "isleaf": 1,
                        "name": "8",
                        "parent_id": 7
                    }
                ],
                "detect_obj": None,
                "isleaf": 0,
                "name": "7",
                "parent_id": 6
            }
        ],
        "detect_obj": None,
        "isleaf": 0,
        "name": "6",
        "parent_id": None
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty easily write a recursive filter function that either modifies your existing tree or (more easily) creates a new copy of it with only the items you want to include. I'm not sure if I've correctly understood the criteria you want to filter on, but here's my best attempt:

```
def filter_tree(tree):
    new_tree = []
    for item in tree:
        if item['is_leaf'] == 1 and item['detect_obj'] == 1: # filter leaves on detect_obj
            new_tree.append(item)
        else:
            new_children = filter_tree(item['children']) # recursively filter non-leaf nodes
            if new_children:          # and filter them out if they have no children left
                new_item = item.copy()
                new_item['children'] = new_children
                new_tree.append(new_item)
    return new_tree
```

This function will return a rough copy of the tree, leaving the original version unmodified. Non-leaf nodes will be copied so their "children" lists can be updated, but leaf nodes will are not copied.

Answer (score 0):

This will filter top level nodes with `detect_obj == 1`.

```
tree = ...
tree = [node for node in tree if node["detect_obj"] == 1]
```

This will filter all levels of the tree with specified predicate

```
def filter_nodes(tree, predicate):
  result = []
  for node in tree:
    if predicate(node):
      clone = node.copy()
      clone['children'] = filter_nodes(clone['children'], predicate)
      result.append(clone)
  return result

tree = ...
print(filter_nodes(tree, lambda node: node['detect_obj'] == 1))
```

Comment: I want to filter all level

Comment: do you want to modify the existing tree or create a clone?